# How to hide Sitecore Client

Tags: client, sitecore

Is there a way to hide the Sitecore client, so it cannot be accessed via http://hostname/sitecore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several options to achieve that.

1. IP Level Restriction
2. Disable Access
3. Delete the entire folder.

(They are explained in details here:
For 3 - [Removing the Sitecore Client](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Security/Removing%20the%20Sitecore%20Client.aspx)
For 1 and 2 - [Restrict Access To The cleint](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/xdb_configuration/restrict_access_to_the_client?sc_lang=en)
)

You can also check the verison specific Security Hardening Guide for the instance (like this one [here](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/62/sitecore_security_hardening_guide-usletter.pdf))

Comment: I went the "Disable Anonymous IIS access" way and it works, but now a an "HTTP-Error 401.2 - Unauthorized" page shows up. My already set up error pages don't seem to catch this one. Is there any way to catch this with a custom error page?

Comment: Not possible I believe. It is IIS level.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to rename the /sitecore folder? I tried that, but I couldn't get onto the client with the renamed folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1) Remove the folder /sitecore/login or simply rename

This prevents logging in to the content editor.

2) Remove the file /sitecore/admin/login.aspx

This prevents access to the admin tools.

Comment: I still would like to access the backend with a renamed /sitecore folder. I renamed it, but then it didn't work anymore. Is this even possible?

Comment: I think Sitecore requires the /sitecore folder to be the way it is so renaming is not possible.  Can you fire up another IIS Sitecore instance that is not publicly facing with the /sitecore folder intact and just run your tools there?  As long as the connection strings of the public and private sites are pointing to the same master/core/web dbs then the content will be the same across both instances.